# MongoDB \uXXXX issue

Tags: regex, mongodb, unicode

In my collection following query returns some result:

```
db.c.find({t:/a/})
```

But below query (and any other regex that has `\uXXXX`) returns no result:

```
db.c.find({t:/\u0041/})
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is that according to [the documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-RegularExpressions)

> MongoDB uses PCRE for regular expressions.

However the PCRE documentation says

> The following Perl escape sequences are not supported: \l, \u, \L,
>          \U, and \N when followed by a character name or Unicode value.  (\N  on
>          its own, matching a non-newline character, is supported.) In fact these
>          are implemented by Perl's general string-handling and are not  part  of
>          its  pattern  matching engine. If any of these are encountered by PCRE,
>          an error is generated by default. However, if the  PCRE_JAVASCRIPT_COMPAT
>          option is set, \U and \u are interpreted as JavaScript interprets
>          them.

That said, [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890467/matching-multibyte-utf8-characters-in-mongodb-regular-expression) may be of some help.

Answer (score 3):

Using Ray Toal's answer, Using PCRE `\x{XXXX}` syntax instead of JavaScript `\uXXXX` solved problem.

```
db.c.find({t:/\x{0041}/})
```

Comment: Wow, this answer from nearly 7 years ago still works. Nice one.